# Area around text & objects looks pixelated after saving

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, pixel, blur

I am using Photoshop CS6 to create a banner of size "500X420" and used resolution 300 PPI. But when i save the image. It looks pixelated around text and object on the image. Please see attached image below.

[image: Looks Bad around Text.]

Kindly help me for this.

Comment: are you exporting as a JPG?

Comment: Are you talking about the text itself being pixelated or the artefacts on the background near the text?

Answer (score 2):

500x420 is the only thing that matters. PPI has no effect on the image in this case because its completely dominated by pixel count. Pixelation (AKA aliasing) is just because you've zoomed in too much. Either you do not want a image at 500x420 or you want the image to be smaller. Your call.

Ok, its been brought up that you might mean the compression artifacts. This is a feature of jpeg compression. The more you compress the more they show up. Ideally you would use something like save for web to preview them. But many distribution networks may compress images if they are larger than some size so you might not have any choice. Ideally you would compress pictures with big uniform areas with a different algorithm like the one used by a PNG image

Comment: thanks for the reply. that is correct that here i have zoomed in above image. But pixelation also looks only on 100% zoomed image. Also the thing is pixelation only looks around text or image, not on other area. Kindly see the background it's looking perfect.

Comment: @Cai jpg compression artifacts? Very common near shape's borders even when the colors are solid

Comment: @Luciano oh yeh maybe... I though OP was talking about the text itself being pixelated

Comment: 100% does not always mean what you think it means @SameerKorde many applications have different notions of 100%. So for example a PDF viewer might think 100% is physical size, or many browsers especially on mobile think 100% is actually 200% zoomed in so to make legacy apps work comfortably, unless you tell it otherwise etc etc.

Comment: @Luciano added stuff on that